# LED strip keeps blowing transistor

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, led, resistors, led-strip

I made two LED controllers using an ESP. On the PCB I'm using three 2N2222 transistors + resistor (1k Ohm) at the base to control the 12V circuit powering the LED strips by applying 3.3V from the ESP.
Schematic (Q1, Q2 and Q3 have been replaced by the transistors):
[image]

Now I've got a problem: On one of the two controllers the Q2 transistor keeps blowing (Q2 is RED, not GREEN, as I accidentally mixed something up). It seems to be the LED strip, because I put it in place of the other controller and now it's working fine.

Could the problem be that the LED strip is too long? Or is there something faulty and I need to replace the whole strip?
If more info is needed, I'll gladly provide it.

Edit: I still have the original controller, which uses an IR remote. If there's anything I need to measure while the strip is on, I can do that too.

The resistor soldered to the base of the transistor works, I just checked that. The red LEDs start flickering, and at some point the transistor blows

Comment: A 2n2222 transistor is not rated for particularly high power, so it's entirely possible that you're overtaxing it.

Comment: @microtherion The thing is, this is the only one blowing out of the 6 I'm using total (3 per board, 2 boards). Also, what would be more critical, the 12V or the amperes (idk how much I have tbh)?

Comment: What LED strip? Asking us to figure out why the transistor blowing and then not giving information as to how you set the circuit up (schematic) with part numbers is like asking us to fix a car without telling us who makes it and what model it is.

Comment: @VoltageSpike it's a 2m smd 5050 strip, some cheap china thing. I ordered two, cut one down to about 1,7m and left the other at 2m. The short one is the one working. They run at 12V

Comment: @matthesinator what model number of LED?

Comment: @VoltageSpike I don't know how to find that out. There's nothing written on the strip and it came in a super cheap packaging, which I've thrown away. Cheap china stuff

Comment: Is there a reason you took the irlb8721 out?

Comment: @VoltageSpike there is: The irlb8721 didn't output enough power at 3.3V. It would output ~6V while I need 12V. I saw the 2n2222 + resistor used in another online tutorial for the same thing, and decided to go with that instead, since I had those at home

Comment: @matthesinator One thing isn't very clear to me. I gather you bought 2m 5050 strips. And it sounds like you bought ones that are "all red" or "all green" or "all blue." You didn't buy the various "white" varieties that are also available. Is that correct? (It would make a lot of sense that you'd have a PCB with three separate switches, one each for red, green and blue -- if you didn't buy the white varieties of 5050 LED strips. If I am getting that wrong and you bought white ones then I am having difficulty understanding your writing. Could you make sure I understand by being explicit?

Comment: @matthesinator (If you did buy separate color strips then it would make sense to me that the red strip would place added burdens on your switching 2N2222 device.)

Comment: @jonk I bought RGB 5050 strips. The LEDs on the strip are RGB, so no individual red/green/blue leds. The transistor for the color red keeps blowing, blue and green are fine

Comment: @matthesinator one possible reason for red blowing up, as opposed to the other colors, is that red LEDs tend to have a lower forward voltage, so the current flowing would be higher than with the other LEDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most 2n2222 transistors have a max Ic collector current of 800mA. If each LED (only one color) drew 20mA and you had 60 (usually what a 2m strip has) of them that would be 1.2A which means you'll burn the transistor out. If your using this with a controller, then it could source amps of current which will also kill the transistor.

The other problem with modifying the schematic is NPN's are lossy and generate loads of heat under high currents. It would be better if you stuck with the original irlb8721's as a low side switch.   They must be used as a low side switch and not high side.

Comment: So cutting the strip down would solve this problem? How can I measure the amps, I'm pretty new to this. Also, I replaced the mosfets since they didn't output enough volts

Comment: Were you planning the load on the source or the drain?

Comment: @matthesinator Another option would be to use a different transistor, too, of course. A TIP31 would be an easy enough BJT to use for this. Though a FET still seems a better option.

Comment: @VoltageSpike Gate was connected to the ESP and would get 3.3V or nothing. Drain was connected to the strip, and Source was connected to the ground

Comment: @Hearth any tip (hehe) on what FET to get? Or better, a tip on where to look for transistors, in case I need to look for some in the future? thanks

Comment: @matthesinator digi-key, mouser, and newark are the big three for electronic components.